# MySql-Pivot Table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have a database table (return_period) having records

```
id  ReturnPeriod    Value   Date
1   10              10X     11/1/2012
2   20              20x     11/1/2012
3   30              30x     11/1/2012
4   10              10xx    12/1/2013
5   20              20xx    12/1/2013
6   30              30y     1/1/2015
7   30              303     1/1/2015
```

and expecting an output table like below:

```
Date      Rp10_Value    Rp20_Value  Rp30_Value
11/1/2012    10x          20x         30x
12/1/2013    10XX         20XX  
1/1/2015                              30y
1/1/2015                              303
```

I want records based on the dates(want the multiple records).Is there a way I can write a query to this type of requirement.Thanks

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pivot.  In MySQL, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select rp.date,
       max(case when returnperiod = 10 then value end) as rp10_value,
       . . .
from return_period rp
group by rp.date;
```

EDIT:

I see you have duplicates.  The same idea applies, but you need to include a sequence number:

```
select rp.date,
       max(case when returnperiod = 10 then value end) as rp10_value,
       . . .
from (select rp.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date, returnperiod order by date) as seqnum
      from return_period rp
     ) rp
group by rp.date, seqnum;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but I am not aiming for the max value.I want all the values.

Comment: @srividyabommineni . . . Easily missed in your question.  That is also easily handled using window functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
select date,
case when rp=10 then value else null end as Rp10_Value,
case when rp=10 then value else null end as Rp20_Value,
case when rp=10 then value else null end as Rp30_Value

from
(
SELECT date, value,  ReturnPeriod
FROM Table2 where ReturnPeriod=10
union all
SELECT date, value,  ReturnPeriod
FROM Table2 where ReturnPeriod=20
union all
SELECT date, value,  ReturnPeriod
FROM Table2 where ReturnPeriod=30
) ;
```

Comment: it seems to get all the values for me but the table looks some thing like this:

Comment: it seems to get all the values for me but the table looks some thing like this Date Rp10_Value Rp20_Value Rp30_Value
 11/1/2012 10x          null            null
 11/1/2012 10XX null            null
 11/1/2012 null          20x                 null
 12/1/2013 null         20xx         null
 1/1/2015   null          null                 30Y
 1/1/2015   null          null                303